# Default behaviour implemented to pure virtual function

Tags: c++, pure-virtual

I've read that Scott Meyers suggest default behaviour to virtual functions to be:

```
class base
{
.....
protected:
   void vfDefault();
public:
   virtual void vf() = 0;
};
```

when it is implemented in a derived class

```
class d1:public base
{
   virtual vf()
   {
       vfDefault();
       ....
   }
};
```

But it is possible also to implement the pure virtual function and use it as default behaviour:

```
class base
{
...
public:
   virtual void vf() = 0;
}
void base::vf()
{
 .....
};
```

when it is implemented in a derived class

```
class d1:public base
{
   virtual vf()
   {
       base::vf();
       ....
   }
};
```

is there any disadvatage of using a pure virtual function inmplementation for default behaviour?

Comment: Please post **real code** in  your questions. I added a bunch of required semicolons.

Comment: One problem with your approach is that it conflates two things (what to override, and what to call for default behavior). Another problem is that some maintainance programmer may be unfamiliar with the technique of implementing a pure virtual, so, may fail to understand the code. A third problem is that it exposes that internal default behavior to client code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `vfDefault()` and `vf()` have different access specifiers. Everybody can call `base::vf()`, including directly calling  base implementation. But only children of the `base` can call `vfDefault()`. So if you implement default behaviour as a separate protected function you can be sure that external code can't call it directly.

Comment: "including directly calling base implementation." - how this could be possible if base class can not be instantiated itself?

Comment: Like this: `child.base::vf();`. Here child is an instance of derived class but we explicitly specify which implementation must be called.

Answer (score 0):

Another disadvantage of using implementation of pure virtual function is the foollowing case:

At the beginning there maybe one default behaviour for for function vf. There is possibility after time to have  new common behaviour for derived classes. In that case there is no other option, except putting new protected common function and loosing consistence. For example:

Classes D1,D2,D3,D4 inherited class Base.Classes D1,D2,D3 use vfDefault then appeared classes D5 and D6 using new common behaviour.